# ActiveAdmin with Devise Rails login twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, activeadmin

I have a `Rails` app that was already setup to use `devise` with `User` model. I just add `ActiveAdmin` and it uses a separate model name `AdminUser`. This new model also uses devise. The problem that I have is:

When I go to `localhost:3000/admin` - the admin login page, the app directs me first to `localhost:3000/users/sign_in` - the general user login page. In other words, to go to admin page, I have to login twice.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to add this into `config/initializer/active_admin.rb`:

```
config.skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

And it works.

Comment: For Rails >= 4.00, use: `config.skip_before_action :authentication_user!`