# before_filter :unless & namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to do the following:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :unless => (:devise_controller? || self.class.parent == 'admin')
```

devise_controller? bit works (I think!) but I'm struggling with getting it to correctly detect the namespace (I'm using ActiveAdmin).

Any thoughts?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to use a proc in your before_filter method. Try something like this

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :unless => Proc.new { devise_controller? || self.class.parent   == 'admin' }
```

For a few code a proc or lambda is enough. If it gets more complicated, extracts the conditions in method my_conditions_method and call `:unless => :my_conditions_method`

Comment: Ruby disagrees: application_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: I forgot the Proc.new

Comment: No errors, but unfortunately no different behaviour than before.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get to the bottom of this as above, but found a solution via this approach, which achieves the same result with a cleaner implementation:

[ActiveAdmin with Devise Rails login twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834443/activeadmin-with-devise-rails-login-twice)

Comment: Did you implement either of the amended solutions provided?

Comment: How can you reasonably argue that this solution addresses your question whatsoever?

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution and several varieties of it, and even though it *should* work (I really can't figure out why it isn't), it didn't. In the interests of GTD, I backed up and took a different path. I do appreciate your contributions very much though.